# Gauss-Jordan elimination/matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Hello guys i got a problem from university and i cant seem to find the answer

This is the problem :
 ka+b+c+d=1
                      a+kb+c+d=1
                      a+b+kc+d=1
                      a+b+c+kd=1

I should solve it using the "k" parameter.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

We see that this represents the matrix
$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc} k&1&1&1 \\ 1&k&1&1 \\ 1&1&k&1 \\ 1&1&1&k \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c} a\\b\\c\\d\end{array}\right]
= \left[\begin{array}{c} 1\\1\\1\\1\end{array}\right].$$
Hence, we should solve this system of linear equations using the augmented matrix
$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} k&1&1&1&1 \\ 1&k&1&1&1 \\ 1&1&k&1&1 \\1&1&1&k&1 \end{array}\right].$$

We can solve the system by performing Gauss-Jordan Elimination on this augmented matrix. Note that this system is likely only solvable for a certain set of $k$. If you assume $k \neq -3$, You will see that the solution is $x_i = \frac{1}{3+k}, i \in [4].$ I recommend you see why this is not solvable when $k = -3.$